# How to disable antialiasing in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, fonts, antialiasing

OS is Debian Wheezy XFCE. Eclipse Version: 3.8.0. Fonts are horribly blurred. I already disabled it systemwide. But in Eclipse fonts are still anit-aliased.

Comment: What OS? What Eclipse version?

Comment: No. ;) Sorry for missing infos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, it might be better to ask about this on https://superuser.com/

I don't know what you did to disable antialiasing system-wide, but there's a nice write-up [here](http://flossblog.wordpress.com/2012/03/02/arreglando-fuentes-feas-ugly-fonts-en-gnulinux/) on how to get sharp fonts with your configuration. It's in Spanish, so here's a summary:

Step 1: Enable subpixel rendering:

```
$ mkdir ~/.fonts.conf.d
$ ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/10-sub-pixel-rgb.conf ~/.fonts.conf.d
```

Step 2: Create `$HOME/.fonts.conf` with the following contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>

  <!-- settings go here -->
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="hinting" mode="assign">
      <bool>true</bool>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font">
    <edit name="hintstyle" mode="assign">
      <const>hintfull</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
  <match target="font">
    <edit mode="assign" name="lcdfilter">
      <const>lcddefault</const>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Also see [this forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=134575) for other info on what to do about font problems with XFCE4.

However, for a discouraging message, take a look at [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1232080), where the verdict is that because Eclipse doesn't use GTK+, there's nothing you can do at the OS level. There also seems to be an [Eclipse open bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=374543) relevant to this.

Sorry I can't offer a more definitive answer.